# Flutter : Handling speech.OnError flutter speech

Tags: flutter, dart

I have app with feature speech recognition , I'm using [Flutter Speech Package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_speech#-example-tab-). Everything is fine , i can Listen , Stop , and Cancel Voice. But the problem is , I can't handling error which is given of this package.

In my console i can see number of error message like this :

```
I/flutter (21660): _platformCallHandler call speech.onSpeechAvailability true
I/flutter (21660): _platformCallHandler call speech.onSpeechAvailability false
I/flutter (21660): _platformCallHandler call speech.onError 4 <================
I/flutter (21660): _platformCallHandler call speech.onSpeechAvailability true
I/flutter (21660): _platformCallHandler call speech.onRecognitionStarted null
I/flutter (21660): _platformCallHandler call speech.onSpeech
I/flutter (21660): _platformCallHandler call speech.onSpeechAvailability false
I/flutter (21660): _platformCallHandler call speech.onError 7 <================
```

In [Example of Package](https://github.com/jaumard/flutter_speech_recognition/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart), already given method `_speech.setErrorHandler()`, I want to display different message error based of error number. How can i do this ?

> Until now , I only display 1 message error for all type of error.

#### My Source Code :

```
class FabVoiceCustom extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FabVoiceCustomState createState() => _FabVoiceCustomState();
}

//TODO Munculkan Tombol Stop Ketika Listen = True
class _FabVoiceCustomState extends State<FabVoiceCustom> {
  SpeechRecognition _speechRecognition;
  bool _isListening = false;
  bool _isAvailable = false;
  String resultText = "";
  final TaskProvider taskProvider = TaskProvider();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initSpeechRecognizer();
  }

  void initSpeechRecognizer() {
    _speechRecognition = SpeechRecognition();

    _speechRecognition.setAvailabilityHandler(
        (bool result) => setState(() => _isAvailable = result));

    _speechRecognition.setRecognitionStartedHandler(
        () => setState(() => _isListening = true));

    _speechRecognition.setRecognitionResultHandler(
        (String speech) => setState(() => resultText = speech));

    _speechRecognition.setRecognitionCompleteHandler((String speech) {
      setState(() => _isListening = false);
      BotToast.showSimpleNotification(title: resultText);
      taskProvider.addTask(
          taskModel: TaskModel()
            ..idTask = DateTime.now()
            ..titleTask = resultText
            ..imageTask = null
            ..dateCreate = DateTime.now()
            ..codeIcon = -1);
    });

    _speechRecognition.setErrorHandler(() {
      BotToast.showText(text: "Something Wrong. Try Again");
      initSpeechRecognizer();
      setState(() {
        _isListening = false;
      });
    });

    _speechRecognition
        .activate("en_US")
        .then((result) => setState(() => _isAvailable = result));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mqHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return WatchBoxBuilder(
      box: Hive.box("language_box"),
      builder: (ctx, box) {
        var isEngland = box.get("isEngland", defaultValue: true);
        return FloatingActionButton.extended(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          label: Text(_isListening ? " Stop" : "Say It"),
          icon: Image.asset(
            _isListening
                ? "assets/images/listen.png"
                : "assets/images/voice.png",
            width: mqHeight / 18,
          ),
          onPressed: _isListening
              ? () {
                  if (_isListening) {
                    _speechRecognition.stop().then((result) => setState(() {
                          _isListening = result;
                          print("result Stop : $result");
                        }));
                  }
                }
              : () {
                  if (_isAvailable && !_isListening) {
                    _speechRecognition
                        .activate(isEngland ? "en_US" : "id_ID")
                        .then((_) => _speechRecognition.listen());
                  }
                },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For onError 4 ====> Server sends error status.
For onError 7 ====> No recognition result matched.

also, you can see the documentation, it will help you.
====>  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html